# Как найти элемент ассоциативной коллекции по значению одного из атрибутов?

Tags: oracle, plsql, коллекции

Допустим, загружаю данные в коллекцию с типм элементов `ROWTYPE`.

Как извлечь отдельные атрибуты элементов коллекции, если передавать `id` в качестве параметра без использования цикла?

```
create table emp (id number, name varchar2(20), age number);
insert into emp values(10,'Tom',20);
insert into emp values(20,'Nicole',30);
commit;

declare
    TYPE emp_t IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    emp_tab emp_t;
begin
    select id,name,age bulk collect into emp_tab from emp;
    for idx in 1..emp_tab.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(emp_tab(idx).name);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

То есть, ожидаю результат: `emp_tab(20).name = Nicole`.

---

PS версия в оригинальном вопросе - 11G.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle PL/SQL: search record type value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64766954) от участника [@Tomic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257032/tomic)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64766954

Answer (score 2):

Надо индексировать коллекцию по `emp.id`. Но для заполнения ее результатом запроса нельзя будет использовать `bulk collect`, по крайней мере не в 11g, это возможно будет добавлленно в [версии 20c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758).

```
declare
    type emptab is table of emp%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    emps emptab;
    id emp.id%type;
begin
    for r in (select id, name, age from emp) loop
        emps(r.id).name := r.name;
        emps(r.id).age  := r.age;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line (emps(20).name||' age='||emps(20).age);
end;
/
Nicole age=30
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770212) от участника [@William Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230471/william-robertson)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Для инициализации ассоциативной коллекции с ключом, полученным как занчение одной из колонок, можно для более эффективного `FETCH` воспользоваться `BULK COLLECT`, а затем, одноразово индексировать коллекцию.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
declare
    type emparr is table of emp%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    rc sys_refcursor;
    emps emparr;
    function initarr (rc sys_refcursor) return emparr is
        res emparr; 
        ret emparr;
    begin 
        fetch rc bulk collect into res;
        close rc;
        for i in 1..res.count loop
            ret(res(i).id).id   := res(i).id; 
            ret(res(i).id).name := res(i).name; 
            ret(res(i).id).age  := res(i).age;
        end loop;    
        return ret;  
    end;
begin
    open rc for select * from emp;
    emps := initarr (rc);
    dbms_output.put_line ('name='||emps(20).name||' age='||emps(20).age);
end;
/
name=Nicole age=30
```